# Declarative Jenkisfile trigger downstream pipeline when dependency is built

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any way to use the trigger downstream pipeline function when a dependency is built from the Pipeline Maven Integration [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven) in a declarative Jenkisfile?

There is a promising TODO on the Jenkis plugin site.

> Using "withMaven" with "docker.image(...).inside{...}" to a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline
>
> TODO provide a sample with Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Has anybody done that yet?

In my use case, I would like to trigger all downstream pipelines when a snapshot is built without using the GUI (I would prefer an infrastructure as code approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, where the exact problem should be. Theoretically it should be

```java
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'openjdk:8-jdk'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            withMaven() {
                sh 'mvn clean install'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax would be to use $MVN_CMD in the withMaven(). That will load the maven spy of the Jenkins Maven plugin.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'openjdk:8-jdk'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            withMaven() {
                sh '$MVN_CMD clean install'
            }
        }
    }
}
```